# Getting NPE while parse empty cells in apache poi?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

```
protected List<List<XSSFCell>> read2DTable(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    LOGGER.debug("read2DTable START");
    List<XSSFCell> headerCells = readTableHeader(sheet);
    List<List<XSSFCell>>  allRows = IntStream.range(sheet.getFirstRowNum(), sheet.getLastRowNum()+1)
                .mapToObj(i -> sheet.getRow(i))
                .map(row -> headerCells.stream()
                                       .map(col -> row.getCell(col.getColumnIndex()))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .filter(c -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(c.toString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    LOGGER.info("rows read: {}, columns read: {}", allRows, headerCells.size());
    LOGGER.info("read2DTable END");

    return allRows;
}
```

This is the error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.netcracker.solutions.gtdc.cim.importdata.processing.excel.ExcelProcessor.lambda$null$9(ExcelProcessor.java:162)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at com.netcracker.solutions.gtdc.cim.importdata.processing.excel.ExcelProcessor.lambda$read2DTable$10(ExcelProcessor.java:162)
```

that happens in here :

```
     .map(col -> row.getCell(col.getColumnIndex()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
.filter(c ->StringUtils.isNotEmpty(c.toString()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Downvoting as it's part of the job to find and fix the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
StringUtils.isNotEmpty(c.toString())
```

with:

```
StringUtils.isNotEmpty(null == c ? "" : c.toString())
```

or avoiding using 3rd party libraries and a bit shorter (as suggested by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)):

```
c!=null && !c.toString().isEmpty()
```

Comment: You mean `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(c)` ;)

Comment: I am afraid I erred; c is not of type String - sorry; I was led astray by isNotEmpty handling null.

Comment: When you use `null == c ? "" : c.toString()`, there is no need for that 3rd party library method anymore, you could invoke `isEmpty()` on the now-non-`null` string, i.e. `! (null == c ? "" : c.toString()).isEmpty()`, but of course, it’s not necessary to substitute the string with an empty string just to test it for emptiness afterwards. So the expression simplifies to `c!=null && !c.toString().isEmpty()`.

Comment: But looking at the surrounding context, `c` is a `List<XSSFCell>`, so even if it is empty, its string representation will be `[]`, i.e. never empty. Also, it’s the result of `.collect(Collectors.toList())` of the inner stream operation in the preceding `map` step, thus it’s never `null`. So it should be `.filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())` instead and is not the actual cause of the `NullPointerException`. My best guess is, `row` is `null` two lines earlier.

Comment: @Holger please convert your comment to an answer. It should be accepted and eligible for upvoting

Comment: @BorisPavlović I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Filter all empty cells:

```
List<List<XSSFCell>>  allRows = IntStream.range(sheet.getFirstRowNum(), sheet.getLastRowNum()+1)
        .mapToObj(i -> sheet.getRow(i))
        .map(row -> headerCells.stream()
                .map(col -> row.getCell(col.getColumnIndex()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .filter(Obejcts::nonNull)
        .filter(c -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(c.toString()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential candidate for being `null` is the result of [`getRow`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getRow-int-), acquired in `.mapToObj(i -> sheet.getRow(i))`, but first dereferenced in the `.map(col -> row.getCell(col.getColumnIndex()))` line.

Also note that the last `filter` is questionable, as you are using a utility function for testing a potentially `null` string for emptyness, but the result of `List.toString()` is never `null` and never empty, as the representation of an empty `List` will be `"[]"`.

The fixed code would look like:

```
List<List<XSSFCell>> allRows
  =IntStream.range(sheet.getFirstRowNum(), sheet.getLastRowNum()+1)
            .mapToObj(i -> sheet.getRow(i)) // you may also use .mapToObj(sheet::getRow)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(row -> headerCells.stream()
                                   .map(col -> row.getCell(col.getColumnIndex()))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the inner lists still can contain `null` elements, depending on the configured [`MissingCellPolicy`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/?org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html). Configuring the workbook to always get blank cells, is preferable to removing `null` elements from the row lists, to keep the list indices of all row lists aligned.